# Is there a way to make Python List by Input Prompt?

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I'm creating a Python mailing List, but I had a problem at the end of function.

Problem is, the List must be like this:

```
['first@google.com', 'second@google.com', 'third@google.com']
```

My current code:

```
mailinputs = raw_input('Enter all mails with comma: ')
receivers = [mailinputs]
```

If you type:

```
'first@google.com', 'second@google.com', 'third@google.com'
```

An error comes up like this:

```
Probe failed: Illegal envelope To: address (invalid domain name):
```

Else, If you type:

```
first@google.com, second@google.com, third@google.com
```

Only first@google.com receives the mail.

What should I do?

Comment: You mean a list, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return of `raw_input()` is a string. You need to split it on the comma, then you'll get a list:

```
>>> 'first@google.com,second@google.com,third@google.com'.split(',')
['first@google.com', 'second@google.com', 'third@google.com']
```

So in your example:

```
mailinputs = raw_input('Enter all mails with comma: ')
receivers = mailinputs.split(',')
```

Another step can be done to remove any whitespace before/after each email:

```
mailinputs = raw_input('Enter all mails with comma: ')
receivers = [x.strip() for x in mailinputs.split(',')]
```